# Excel Add-ins freezing Excel

Tags: excel, office365, excel-addins

A little background.  I started having issue with Excel last week and am working from home (connected to the company network).  I was working as a contractor (Employee ID 123ABC) for a company that I had previously worked for (Employee ID 789XYZ).  2 weeks ago, I was rehired as a full time employee and was given my old employee ID 789XYZ.  I am using the same laptop for both Employee ID 123ABC and 789XYZ   The Contractor Employee ID (123ABC) has supposedly been disabled.

My issue appears to be with Add-Ins.  Any time I open an Excel file (mostly xlsm) it seems to start loading but takes forever before it is fully loaded.  Many of these xlsm files have "on open routines" that check for specific add-ins.  Multiple times it has taken 20 minutes for a file to be "usable".  These files are relatively small (under 200 kbs) and do not contain data or excessive formatting. (We've learned over the years not to do some of these things)

Add-ins are stored in "C:\Users(employee id)\AppData\Roaming|Microsoft\Addins.  We are using Office 365.  All updates have been installed on the laptop.

The Help Desk as repaired Office, removed Office and re-installed 32 bit Office.  Then when the issue still occurred, They removed 32 bit and installed 64 bit Office with no resolution.  My guess is there is still some link to the "old" contractor ID but that is just a guess.

I can go to File > Options and click any button and the pop-up performs like I'm used.  However, if I click the "Addins" option, Excel freezes.  If I try and click on anything on the pop-up, Excel freezes and I see "not responding" displayed in the file name.  At this point, I have to close Excel; which has become exceedingly challenging and takes multiple attempts to close even from Task Manager.

The interesting thing is I can open these files (stored in my C:\Temp\ folder), before connecting to the network, and Excel behaves like it used to.  It opens and loads quickly.  I can navigate to File > Options > Addins and it doesn't freeze Excel and goes to Addin part of the popup.

Of course, I can't run these macros because they reach in to a database on the network to retrieve employee information.

I been on the phone with the Help Desk for the last 3 days and no one can seem to figure out what is going on.  My guess is something was not transitioned properly from employee id 123ABC to 789XYZ.

I'm hoping someone has experienced something similar and may provide a suggestion.  Thanks for taking the time to look at this question....

Comment: You can check the registry entries: Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Add-in Manager - maybe there are some strange references

Comment: @Ike.....Thanks...........We'll take a look at those entries...Appreciate the help....

Comment: Disable macros and test.

Comment: @SolarMike...........Thanks for the suggestion.  Most of these files are macros.  We have removed the add-ins and disabled them and we still have the issue....

Comment: They ended up removing and re-installing Office again.  Once that was done, the issue seemed to go away.......